# How to Angularize Mobile menu with ng-show & ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

http://plnkr.co/edit/F8K66L?p=preview

I have a `li` menu which at `300px` goes to `display:none`, while the `mobile_nav` button turns on.

Now currently in my Controller I'm using this

**main.js**

```
$scope.mobileMenu = function() {
  var menu = document.getElementById('main_nav');

  if (menu.style.display == 'block') {
      menu.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
      menu.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

If I open the mobile menu, then close it, it stays closed on a larger view when resized, even though I have `display:block` in the CSS. Also need the mobile menu to close if an item is clicked inside of it.

Tried this, but without any luck

**index.html**

```
<div
  ng-click="isMobileNavOpen = !isMobileNavOpen"
  class="mobile_nav">
  =
</div>

<nav id="main_nav" ng-init="isMobileNavOpen = true" ng-show="isMobileNavOpen">
  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

style.css

```
// the button
.mobile_nav {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
  .mobile_nav {
    display: block;
  }      

  #main_nav {
    display: none;
  }

  #main_nav li {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom 20px;
  }

  #main_nav a {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the perfect library!

https://github.com/AnalogJ/matchmedia-ng

^ Here is the code that fixed my issue (needed an Angular way to detect size)

```
var unregister = matchmedia.onPhone( function(mediaQueryList){
    $scope.isPhone = mediaQueryList.matches;
});
```

Did have to use the overrides to adjust to my pixel specifications:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['matchmedia-ng']).config(['matchmediaProvider', function (matchmediaProvider) {
    matchmediaProvider.rules.phone = "(max-width: 500px)";
    matchmediaProvider.rules.desktop = "(max-width: 1500px)";
}]);
```

Also had to go ahead with 2 different navs :/ will still try to play around with this a bit to see if I can get it down to using just 1 nav:

```
<div class="mobile_nav noselect">
    <div ng-click="isMobileNavOpen = !isMobileNavOpen" class="icon-menu"></div>
</div>

<nav id="main_nav">

<nav id="mobile_nav" ng-show="isMobileNavOpen">
```